# How to test or get value from state in react?

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

Hi could you please tell me How to test or get value from state in react ?
getting error
**wrapper.instance(...).handleClickShowPassword is not a function**

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/l2lk4n794l

```
it("toggle showpassword value", () => {
    wrapper.setState({ showPassword: false });
    wrapper.instance().handleClickShowPassword();

    expect(wrapper.state.showPassword).toEqual(true);
  });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `LoginContainer` is an wrapped with an HOC, you either need to export the component without `withStyles` HOC or use `dive` on the wrapper to get the instance of the component. Also `state` is a function on `component instance` and hence you need to call it to access state

```
describe("<LoginContainer/>", () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<LoginContainer />);
  });

  it("toggle showpassword value", () => {
    const comp = wrapper.dive();
    comp.dive().setState({ showPassword: false });
    comp.instance().handleClickShowPassword();
    expect(comp.state("showPassword")).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

**[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/1r5v9jlkw3)**